# Webpack giving an error when hot-reloading my react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

When I make a change to my react-app, and it tries to reload, I get the following error:

```
/path/to/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js:50
                    changes = changes.concat(removals);
                                      ^

TypeError: changes.concat is not a function
```

I then have to restart my react app in order for the changes to be reflected.

This started when we did a bunch of fiddling with versions of different packages, so I suspect that there's some combination of packages that webpack is not happy with, but I don't know which ones, or how to figure that out.

Just in case it's relevant, though I don't think it is, here's the webpack section of my craco.config.js:

```
webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new DefinePlugin({
        BRAND_NAME: '"My app"'
      })
    ],
    configure: webpackConfig => {
      const instanceOfMiniCssExtractPlugin = webpackConfig.plugins.find(
        plugin => plugin instanceof MiniCssExtractPlugin
      );

      if (instanceOfMiniCssExtractPlugin)
        instanceOfMiniCssExtractPlugin.options.ignoreOrder = true;

      return webpackConfig;
    }
  }
```

[Package.json link](https://pastebin.com/kXyxcWyN)

Comment: try updating your react-scripts to the latest version

Comment: Done. No impact, I still get the same error.

Comment: can you please share the versions of dependencies that you are using in `package.json`

Comment: Why don't you just check out a working copy of `package.json` and the lockfile from your version control system and update the dependencies one at a time to avoid the issue or at least determine which dep causes the issue?

Comment: @chessguy, a list of scripts from package.json could be helpful, +craco version, +version of other dependencies like webpack

Comment: I've updated to add a link to my package.json file

Answer (score 2):

### Webpack and Watchpack Versions

The error seems to be in reference to [v4 of webpack (or earlier)](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/444e59f8a427f94f0064cae6765e5a3c4b78596d/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js#L50). This function was reworked in [v5 of webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/610f36817af1f1c6929786d68f734ac582af1757/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js#L71-L82), where it now no longer assumes `changes` is an array (it's now an iterable that is only iterated if `inputFileSystem.purge` is defined).

From the resolution section of `package.json`, it looks like you're resolving  `watchpack` to version `2.2.0`. From the [v2 release notes](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/releases/tag/v2.0.0), it looks like it changed its API to now pass sets instead of arrays to `watcher.once("aggregated", (changes, removals) => {...})`, breaking v4 of webpack.

Updating to version 5 of `webpack` may solve this particular issue (though you may need to upgrade other packages that depend on webpack v4, like `webpack-cli`). Alternatively, downgrading `watchpack` to before version 2 (like [version 1.7.5](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/releases/tag/v1.7.5)) might also work, though this may also introduce new issues.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your array before performing the `concat` operation. You can also use the `Array.from()` method before using concat. For example,

```
const arr1 = ['a', 'b'];
const arr2=['d', 'c'];
const arr3 = Array.isArray(arr1) ? arr1.concat(arr2) : []; //check if arr1 is a array
const arr4=Array.from(arr1).concat(arr2); //use type conversion.
```

Try the above methods in the node modules folder of where the error is from.

Comment: The concat isn't being done in my code, it's being done in an NPM dependency.

Comment: @chessguy Sorry, my bad. I have got this kind of error before, so I just made a reference. Just try to delete the `node_modules` and `packages.lock.json` folder and install it again. Then check if the error exist, if it still exist then it it may be an old package try `npm fund` to update the package. thank you.